# Getting error when reffering .NET core project to WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-core

I have .NET EF core (target Framework .NET core 2.0) project which involves only entities. 
This project is refereed in other .NET core project but also in a WCF application (having target Framework .NET 4.6.1), since I need to connect to the database.
For some reason each time when I tried to access the database from WCF application I have the following error:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'

Do you know what could be the reason for this ? As I know, I should be able to refer .NET core project into .NET 4.6 WCF project..

Thanks alot

Comment: WCF projects can only add references of .NET Standard class libraries. You cannot add .NET Core class libraries. https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff

Comment: @Lex Li But I don't want to have multiple entity projects (one for core and one for WCF). There is really nothing to do in this way ?

Comment: First, a .NET Standard class library can be consumed by both. Second, you can also use multi-targeting.